# group by in sql combining values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table (sql 2008) with A,B,C,D,E values in col1
Is there a way to get counts grouped by col1 so that result returned will be

```
A - #
B - #
other - #
```

Thank you

Comment: Have you given anything a try yet?  What did you try?  What were the results?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select
   case when col1 in ('a','b') then col1 else 'other' end,
   count(*)
from tab
group by case when col1 in ('a','b') then col1 else 'other' end
```

Answer (score 6):

Repeating the `CASE` expression works, but I find it a little less tedious to only perform that expression once. Plans are identical.

```
;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT Name = CASE WHEN Name IN ('A','B') THEN Name 
  ELSE 'Other' END
  FROM dbo.YourTable
)
SELECT Name, COUNT(*) FROM x 
GROUP BY Name;
```

If ordering is important (e.g. `Other` should be the last row in the result, even if other names come after it alphabetically), then you can say:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN Name = 'Other' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, Name;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT res.col1, COUNT(*)
FROM
      (SELECT 
      (CASE col1 WHEN 'A' THEN 'A'
                 WHEN 'B' THEN 'B'
                 ELSE 'other'
       END) as col1
       FROM table ) as res
GROUP BY col1
```

[test](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fb92b/3)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT col1, COUNT(col1)
FROM mytable
WHERE col1 IN ('A', 'B')
GROUP BY col1
UNION
SELECT col1, COUNT(col1)
FROM mytable
WHERE col1 IS NULL OR col1 NOT IN ('A','B')
GROUP BY col1
ORDER BY col1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CASE col1
WHEN a then 'nameofnewcolumn'
WHEN b then 'nameofnewcolumn'
ELSE 'other'
END
FROM TABLE
```

This should group all the values into columns and the else groups everything that doesn't fit into an OTHER group.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
SELECT ColumnName, COUNT(ColumnName)
    FROM NyTable
    GROUP BY ColumnName
```

Answer (score 0):

If 'other' should be the last row, and 'A', 'B' actually can be arbitrary (e.g. 'plums', 'zillion'), the following can be used:

```
;with cte as (
    select
        col1 = case when t.col1 in ('A', 'B') then t.Col1 else 'other' end,
        ordnum = case when t.col1 in ('A', 'B') then 0 else 1 end
    from TableName
)
select col1, count(1)
from cte
group by col1
order by ordnum, col1
```